# php dynamic page as email body

Tags: php, html, email

This is the scenario,A user select a plan from a planning page,once he selected a plan that will be shown in a table,so he wants his plan on email,so how can set email body as his selected plan page.If is there any solution please help me.

Comment: Please be a bit more descriptive when you refer to what you're trying to send in an email body. Is the plan an image? text? or a combination of both?

Comment: I am displaying plan detail text in table format on same page after selecting plans,below the table i have email option,when he enter his address and submit it then i need to send that table to his email as body of email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two basic steps:

1) Submit the data that you requested using an HTML `form` with the `POST` method. We'll assume that you are keeping this data in a form field named `'plans'`.

2) You can then use the `mail()` function in PHP. Here is an altered example from the [mail() PHP Manual Page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
<?php
    //This belongs in whichever file is called by your HTML form

    $to      = 'yourtarget@example.com';
    $subject = 'Plans';

    //Retrieve the plan contents from the form's posted data
    $message = $_POST['plans_field'];

    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Edit: To get the actual table contents I would probably use some jQuery. Let's assume your table looks like  this:

```
<table>
    <tr><td id="plan_data">Here is all of your plan data!</td></tr>
</table>
```

In addition, you will have a hidden field in your form (since you aren't requesting the user actually provide the data themselves, we will use a hidden field).

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="plans_field" name="plans_field" value="" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

We'll intercept the form submission (since the hidden field is current an empty string) and, using jQuery, we'll populate the hidden field's value with the table cell contents:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#submit").on("click", function() {

        $("#plans_field").val($("#plan_data").html());

    });

});
```

The line inside the on click function might look a bit lengthy, but it's basically saying: "I want to set the value of the hidden plans_field to the contents of the plan_data cell."

Please remember that these are just examples and that my answer is not foolproof: a browser with JavaScript disabled would be able to submit that form and the empty string would remain, so some error checking on your end would be a good idea.

Comment: right now i am dislaying plan detail in table within a div,so can i get that data by calling div id by get or post method?

Comment: See my updated answer with an example of how to get table data into the form at the time of submission.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be using $_GET and/or $_POST methods. I suggest looking up tutorials as to how to use these. It wouldn't take too long as it sounds like a fairly simple problem you need solved.

I would add however, that this is not really an appropriate StackOverflow question. Stack-O is really for specific problems, not for getting someone else to build a whole page for you.

Have a look at [this](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php.html) or something like [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php). They walk you through pretty much everything you need to know about PHP and it's divided into subsections quite nicely. There are places you could find specific PHP tutorials for problems similar to yours, but learning the language properly is a much better way to go.

Note: Homeandlearn use the now deprecated mysql, so I suggest looking up mysqli, or even better PDO if you will be querying databases.

Comment: Thank you,I am not telling to build my pages,Just i m structed in embedding dynamic page on email body,if possible give a solution or give a reference to this problem

Comment: As I described, I can't just give you a solution, especially not without seeing your form and email code. It would help if you showed us what you have already, i.e. html tag names/id's and php code etc. It's simple PHP form submission explained on the pages above.

As for sending the email here is a tutorial on that http://codechirps.com/php-email-contact-form-tutorial/. But seriously, I suggest researching and learning PHP thoroughly instead of looking for an easy-end